# Instantiating a class by String name in Dart

Tags: dart, reflection, mirror

I am trying to call a method of a class that I only know by name as a String. Now therefore I would need a ClassMirror of that class that allowes me to instantiate an instance. However, creating ClassMirrors seems to be only possible by entering a type using `reflectClass(Type)` or by passing an already existing instance of that class into `reflect(dynamic)`. So these aren`t helping if I only have a String.

In Java you can do this pretty easily, by calling `Class.forName(String)`. Then you would get a Constructor instance, make it accessibly and call it.

Does anyone know if this is even possible in dart? What seems weird is that once you have a ClassMirror you can access fields and methods by passing symbols, which can be created by Strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a specific list of strings to map to a specific list of closures to create a new object with specific parameters.

But you can't get a reflection without using dart:mirrors, which is being deprecated, and also had a negative impact on tree shaking to get the payload size down.

In general, you're invited to look at the package:reflectable to achieve most of what you'd want out of dart:mirrors, using source-to-source builders.